# Deleting del word from input in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, replaceall

**Question**
Given a string, if the string "del" appears starting at index 1, return a string where that "del" has been deleted. Otherwise, return the string unchanged.
**My Code**

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  return str.replaceAll("del","");
}
```

but my code failed for some test cases like:
1)delDel("del") → "del" ""
2)delDel("aadelbb") → "aadelbb" "aabb"

I am beginner to Java. Can anyone tell me why it's showing that error.
Question link : https://codingbat.com/prob/p100905 
Thanks in advance...

[image: Image of problem]

Comment: *starting at index 1,* - where is this check?  Also `replaceAll` is for replacing using regex.

Comment: Consider exploring methods of string `startsWith()` and `substring()`

Comment: Thank You  **Scary Wombat**  now it's working

Answer (score 1):

Here `String::replaceFirst` should be used with a simpler regexp `"^(.)del"` because only the first occurrence at the beginning of the string needs to be matched:

```
public String delDel(String str) {
  return str.replaceFirst("^(.)del", "$1");
}
```

---

Another solution may use `String::regionMatches` (or even shorter `String::startsWith`) and `String::charAt` + `String::substring` to perform the task without regular expressions at all:

```java
public String delDel(String str) {
    return str.startsWith("del", 1) ? str.charAt(0) + str.substring(4) : str;
//  return str.regionMatches(1, "del", 0, 3) ? str.charAt(0) + str.substring(4) : str;
}
```

Comment: Why use the complex `regionMatches` rather than the simpler `startsWith("del", 1)`?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire, thanks for the hint, I've been unaware of this overriding for `startsWith`